# Creating System.Windows.Controls and adding Two Way Binding of a Field to a UserControle in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

What i want to do is the Following

Create an UserControle like this:

```
public partial class MyUserControle : UserControl
```

with a Wrappanel inside to add Controls and stuff to

```
<WrapPanel Margin="0,0,0,41" Name="wrapPanel1" />
```

this class has 2 Buttons to Cancel or Apply the Settings in the Window.
The window later gets open like this

```
Window w = new Window();

w.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
w.Content = myClass.getmyUserControle();
bool? t = w.ShowDialog();
```

Where myClass is a special Class that creates the UserControle and adds some stuff it wants to be changed in the WrapPanel

Now in myClass say i have a simple Point

```
  System.Drawing.Point myPoint = new Point(10,15);
```

and getmyUserControle() looks like

```
  public MyUserControle  getmyUserControle(){
      MyUserControle UC = new MyUserControle();
      WPF.TextBox X1 = new WPF.TextBox();
      System.Windows.Data.Binding BindingX = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("X");         
      BindingX.Source = myPoint;
      BindingX.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay;
      X1.SetBinding(WPF.TextBox.TextProperty, BindingX);
      UC.addhere.Add(X1);
      return UC;
  }
```

The Textbox is filled properly but the changes dont change the source. How can i Fix this?

edit: 
I can add a

```
  private MyUserControle myUCsave = null;
```

to the class and set the

```
  myUCsave = UC;
```

at the end of getmyUserControle() and check at the start

```
 myUCsave != null return myUCsave;
```

that fixes the "save" of the textbox, but the underlying myPoint doesnt change.

**Edit**: Maybe there is a more simple Case: i create a simple Form and add this to the MainWindow via constructor

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window   
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
        TextBox X1 = new TextBox();
        TextBox Y1 = new TextBox();
        X1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 20, 20);
        Y1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 100, 100);
        X1.Width = 100;
        Y1.Width = 100;
        X1.Height = 200;
        Y1.Height = 200;
        System.Windows.Data.Binding BindingX = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("X");
        System.Windows.Data.Binding BindingY = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("X");
        BindingX.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingY.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingX.Source = myPoint;
        BindingY.Source = myPoint;
        X1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, BindingX);
        Y1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, BindingY);
        this.MainGrid.Children.Add(Y1);
        this.MainGrid.Children.Add(X1);  
    }

    Point myPoint = new Point(100, 200);
```

This Should Create Two TextBoxes X1,Y1 that are Linked to the same source (myPoint.X)? But when i change one thing the other textbox doesn't change neither does the source.

Comment: Its because you have two different objects of your user control. As in your getmyUserControle() method you have created new object of your usercontrol.Please add your functionality which you wants to achieve. Not Clear enough

Comment: Where do i have two UserControles? I create one in getmyUserControle() but there is no other? i Just add it to the content of the Window?